# How can I click on one image and enlarge it and hide the remaining two images with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html:

```
<div class="Album1">
<ul>
    <li class="pic1"><a href=""><img src="#" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="pic2"><a href=""><img src="#" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="pic3"><a href=""><img src="#"alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I make it where when I click on one of the images it enlarges that image and the other two images disappear and then when I click on the image again it goes back to regular size and the other two images appear?

My js:

```
$(".Album1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var largeImage = $(this).attr("rel");
    console.log(largeImage);

    $(".Album1 a").children().removeClass("currentImage");

    $(largeImage).addClass("currentImage");
});
```

Comment: $(".Album1").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $(this)width(500px);


});

Comment: post is with question, people will like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind event on li element; for example:

> $('.Album1 li').click(function() {
>           $(this).siblings('li').toggle();
>           return false;
>       })

Comment: i'm so happy to help you

Comment: One thing that I have seen is that event.preventDefault(); is now better to use vs return false.  I just wanted to share what I have picked up and help you have stronger code. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: first :event.preventDefault();  it  is just use non-ie stop default action；

Comment: first :event.preventDefault();  it  is just use non-ie stop default action；  second：ie10- is not support use it； last：return false is common method use to stop default action； and  you can test it

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I will keep looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have a larger version of each image (which you should) you can do $().hide() on the other images while using a modal (or dialogue) to popup and display the larger, selected image.

Reverse everything when clicking out the modal or dialogue